# CSS ::after pseudo element clear not working

Tags: html, css, css-float, pseudo-element

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/e4y05yyz/1/

Working on a responsive layout.  I would expect that the :after pseudo element would clear both floats and the the element with class .masthead-middle would drop to the next line, but it does not.  If I put a clear: both; on the masthead-middle element that works, and I can do that, but I don't understand why the float is not clearing based on the :after.  The after pseudo element will be added using a media query, but I can't get it to work in "standard" css.

Here is the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="header-inner">
        <div class="masthead">
            <div class="masthead-inner">
                <div class="masthead-left">LEFT</div>
                <div class="masthead-right">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="masthead-middle">MIDDLE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
header .header-inner {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
header .masthead {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header .masthead .masthead-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header .masthead .masthead-left {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header .masthead .masthead-right {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header .masthead .masthead-right:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

header .masthead .masthead-middle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: i  do not understand the point of that pseudo here ? a float, inline-block or table displayed element doesn't need this to deal with floatting childs.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e4y05yyz/2/ less css does the same , what is it that  you need to clear ?

Comment: I want the element that contains middle to shift to the left.  I want to use a media query to add the after element when the window is below a certain width.  I didn't want to complicate the question with extra CSS at this point because I can't get it to work at all.  Since the order is left, right middle, and left and right are floated, shouldn't an after on the right element cause the middle element to drop?

Comment: @CraigJacobs No it shouldn't. The `::after` pseudo-element generates a pseudo child element for the current selector (at the end of the element). It doesn't mean to select the next sibling! To achieve the latter, you could use `.masthead-right + *` selector (assuming you don't want to select the `.masthead-middle` directly).

Comment: @CraigJacobs okay i see, then you only need to set .right to { clear:left} to see it drop under .left , .middle should remain on spot left on right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a answer with a snippet  to illustrate my comment

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
header .header-inner {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
header .masthead {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header .masthead .masthead-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header .masthead .masthead-left {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header .masthead .masthead-right {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
  clear:left
}


div {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px;
  }
header .masthead .masthead-middle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  background:yellow
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="header-inner">
        <div class="masthead">
            <div class="masthead-inner">
                <div class="masthead-left">LEFT</div>
                <div class="masthead-right">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="masthead-middle">MIDDLE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

add width:100% to see right taking all width avalaible

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
header .header-inner {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
header .masthead {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header .masthead .masthead-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header .masthead .masthead-left {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header .masthead .masthead-right {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
  clear:left
}


div {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px;
  }
header .masthead .masthead-middle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  background:yellow
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="header-inner">
        <div class="masthead">
            <div class="masthead-inner">
                <div class="masthead-left">LEFT</div>
                <div class="masthead-right">RIGHT</div>
                <div class="masthead-middle">MIDDLE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

`clear: both` on `::after` pseudo-element is used in order to clear the floats (of children) at the end of the parent element.

If you want to prevent an element from wrapping the floats, you should give `clear: both` declaration to the element itself.